# Can you reference only one from image gallery for Django/Python?

Tags: python, django

```
 {% for item in page.architecture_images.all %}
                        {% image item.image fill-800x800-c100 %}
                        <p>{{ item.caption }}</p>
                    {% endfor %}
```

Is there a way to call only one image from this gallery that has 2+ images in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) the queryset to only retrieve one item

```
{% for item in page.architecture_images.all|slice:":1" %}
    {% image item.image fill-800x800-c100 %}
    <p>{{ item.caption }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Found some good helpful stuff on top of what you gave me! Thank you https://diveinto.org/python3/native-datatypes.html#slicinglists